# How to auto generate dynamically multiple pages changing keywords and meta keywords

Tags: php, dynamic

I'm new to this but I need to reproduce the same thing as this site is doing for my site too. "Getserialkey.com"

It has a simple page and from all pages are created dynamically by changing just the keyword, all meta tags meta titles meta descriptions will be changed for each page but content template will still be the same.

To do have to template I can reproduce the code in the page source and make changes my own way but how to auto generate many pages dynamically?

Like for example I will have just keywords for a software that I'll input and it will generate the page automatically which will not exactly be the same content because title and tags will be changed.

Please help me do this.

Comment: not 100% sure what you want, but are you looking for a scripting language like PHP ? I'm voting to close this question because it looks not programming related

Comment: Hi XzenTorXz,
Yes I'm looking for a PHP script that can do the job described in the OP :)

Answer (score 0):

for the start you can write a very simple php script:

```
<?php
$keyword = $_GET['key'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $keyword; ?></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Keyword: <?php echo $keyword; ?></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

then you can call the site with: `index.php?key=test` and the keyword test will be shown on the website.

if you want to read the keywords directly from the url you should take a look into `htaccess mod_rewrite`